# Profiling XDP eBPF packet loss and poor performance

Tags: c, ebpf, bpf, xdp-bpf

I have created a small project (https://github.com/NHAS/wag) that uses XDP & eBPF to allow connections based on time over a wireguard VPN.

I have attached the XDP eBPF program to the wireguard TUN device, and am experiencing poor throughput (speedtest of down ~20 Mbps wireguard + eBPF, vs wireguard - eBPF ~100 Mbps). Additionally, pings to the wireguard server itself have inconsistent latency, and are dropped at a rate of 1 ICMP packet/~600 pings.

Please note that this occurs during unloaded periods. Where traffic will be less than 100 Mbps total.

The code below is loaded into the kernel with cilium.

```golang
// Kernel load
...
    xdpLink, err = link.AttachXDP(link.XDPOptions{
        Program:   xdpObjects.XdpProgFunc,
        Interface: iface.Index,
    })
...
```

eBPF kernel:

```c
// +build ignore

#include "bpf_endian.h"
#include "common.h"

char __license[] SEC("license") = "Dual MIT/GPL";

// One /24
#define MAX_MAP_ENTRIES 256

// Inner map is a LPM tri, so we use this as the key
struct ip4_trie_key
{
    __u32 prefixlen; // first member must be u32
    __u32 addr;      // rest can are arbitrary
};

// Map of users (ipv4) to BOOTTIME uint64 timestamp denoting authorization status
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") sessions = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .max_entries = MAX_MAP_ENTRIES,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .map_flags = 0,
};

// Map of users (ipv4) to BOOTTIME uint64 timestamp denoting when the last packet was recieved
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") last_packet_time = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH,
    .max_entries = MAX_MAP_ENTRIES,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .map_flags = 0,
};

// A single variable in nano seconds
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") inactivity_timeout_minutes = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_ARRAY,
    .max_entries = 1,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u64),
    .map_flags = 0,
};

// Two tables of the same construction
// IP to LPM trie
struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") mfa_table = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH_OF_MAPS,
    .max_entries = MAX_MAP_ENTRIES,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .map_flags = 0,
};

struct bpf_map_def SEC("maps") public_table = {
    .type = BPF_MAP_TYPE_HASH_OF_MAPS,
    .max_entries = MAX_MAP_ENTRIES,
    .key_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .value_size = sizeof(__u32),
    .map_flags = 0,
};

/*
Attempt to parse the IPv4 source address from the packet.
Returns 0 if there is no IPv4 header field; otherwise returns non-zero.
*/
static int parse_ip_src_dst_addr(struct xdp_md *ctx, __u32 *ip_src_addr, __u32 *ip_dst_addr)
{
    void *data_end = (void *)(long)ctx->data_end;
    void *data = (void *)(long)ctx->data;

    // As this is being attached to a wireguard interface (tun device), we dont get layer 2 frames
    // Just happy little ip packets

    // Then parse the IP header.
    struct iphdr *ip = data;
    if ((void *)(ip + 1) > data_end)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // We dont support ipv6
    if (ip->version != 4)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Return the source IP address in network byte order.
    *ip_src_addr = (__u32)(ip->saddr);
    *ip_dst_addr = (__u32)(ip->daddr);

    return 1;
}

static int conntrack(__u32 *src_ip, __u32 *dst_ip)
{

    // Max lifetime of the session.
    __u64 *session_expiry = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&sessions, src_ip);
    if (!session_expiry)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // The most recent time a valid packet was received from our a user src_ip
    __u64 *lastpacket = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&last_packet_time, src_ip);
    if (!lastpacket)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // Our userland defined inactivity timeout
    u32 index = 0;
    __u64 *inactivity_timeout = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&inactivity_timeout_minutes, &index);
    if (!inactivity_timeout)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    __u64 currentTime = bpf_ktime_get_boot_ns();

    // The inner map must be a LPM trie
    struct ip4_trie_key key = {
        .prefixlen = 32,
        .addr = *dst_ip,
    };

    // If the inactivity timeout is not disabled and users session has timed out
    u8 isTimedOut = (*inactivity_timeout != __UINT64_MAX__ && ((currentTime - *lastpacket) >= *inactivity_timeout));

    if (isTimedOut)
    {
        u64 locked = 0;
        bpf_map_update_elem(&sessions, src_ip, &locked, BPF_EXIST);
    }

    // Order of preference is MFA -> Public, just in case someone adds multiple entries for the same route to make sure accidental exposure is less likely
    // If the key is a match for the LPM in the public table
    void *user_restricted_routes = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&mfa_table, src_ip);
    if (user_restricted_routes)
    {

        if (bpf_map_lookup_elem(user_restricted_routes, &key) &&
            // 0 indicates invalid session
            *session_expiry != 0 &&
            // If max session lifetime is disabled, or we are before the max lifetime of the session
            (*session_expiry == __UINT64_MAX__ || *session_expiry > currentTime) &&
            !isTimedOut)
        {

            // Doesnt matter if the value is not atomically set
            *lastpacket = currentTime;

            return 1;
        }
    }

    void *user_public_routes = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&public_table, src_ip);
    if (user_public_routes && bpf_map_lookup_elem(user_public_routes, &key))
    {
        // Only update the lastpacket time if we're not expired
        if (!isTimedOut)
        {
            *lastpacket = currentTime;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

SEC("xdp")
int xdp_prog_func(struct xdp_md *ctx)
{
    __u32 src_ip, dst_ip;
    if (!parse_ip_src_dst_addr(ctx, &src_ip, &dst_ip))
    {
        return XDP_DROP;
    }

    if (conntrack(&src_ip, &dst_ip) || conntrack(&dst_ip, &src_ip))
    {

        return XDP_PASS;
    }

    return XDP_DROP;
}
```

The questions I'm looking to answer are:

- How do I profile which areas (if any) of the eBPF program are intensive?
- Is this a processing time limit for XDP, or an optimal time to keep in mind?
- Is my eBPF program sane?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That's a lot of overhead for XDP so most likely reasons are: (1) JIT compiler is disabled or (2) you're attaching to the (slow) generic XDP hook. For (1), what's the value of `/proc/sys/net/core/bpf_jit_enable`? For (2), what's your kernel version and the driver of your NIC?

Comment: 1. The JIT compiler is enabled, so the value is 1. 
Kernel version is 5.15.0 and the NIC driver is virtio-net. 

2. The cilium `AttachXDP`, defaults to using the slow generic XDP hook, so you're dead correct on that point. 

Tangentially, would squashing the lookup into one call help that overhead? 

(Also thanks so much)

Comment: Actually, scratch that, the NIC driver is the TUN device, as this is attached to a wireguard TUN

Comment: Yeah just from testing it the TUN device doesnt support Offload or Driver modes which makes sense

Comment: Ok, that's going to be the biggest source of overhead as the generic XDP mode is after the skb allocation, so you don't get XDP's usual performance benefits. What you do inside the BPF program won't change that.

Comment: Ah interesting, I didnt realise that it was after skb in generic mode. I actually rewrote this to use the TC ebpf hook just to see if that made any difference and it didnt.
Considering Im also running this at low speeds, it makes sense that this is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

For the BPF XDP hook, the most common sources of huge per-packet overhead are:

- JIT compiler is disabled. You can check the value of `/proc/sys/net/core/bpf_jit_enable` for that.
- The driver doesn't support XDP. You need to check this for the specific driver and kernel versions you are using.

As discussed in comments, you're in the second case. Your program is attached to the TUN device which doesn't support the XDP driver mode. That means your BPF program runs after the skb allocation and performance won't be much better than at the tc hook.